# React Native SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' when not debugging in Chrome

Tags: react-native

Whenever I turn off debugging from chrome I get red screen with

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

As soon as I turn on chrome debugger all errors go away. I tried building the bundle by running `react-native bundle --platfrom ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output main.jsbundle` and got the same issue. From the logs I can see the following:

> Worker Farm: Received message for unknown index for existing child.
>   This should not happen! Tue, 21 Jun 2016 22:17:13 GMT
>   ReactNativePackager:SocketServer request error { message: 'Unexpected
>   token: punc (.)',   filename: 0,   line: 19,   col: 6,   pos: 964,
>   stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at 
>   (/Users/aaa/bbb/src/ccc/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1),
>   .......

I cannot figure out which '.' exactly the packager is complaining and how Chrome debugging makes the error go away.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently packager does not like 'new.target' syntax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target). If anyone knows a fix to this that would be great!

Comment: I remove the new.target and it works for me, thx for you help

Answer (score 1):

When you're not using debug mode, your JS script is evaluated by JavascriptCore, otherwise by V8. JavascriptCore is a pure JS environment, therefore many APIs won't work as long as FB does not make a polyfill for it. Therefore you might need to find another way or some polyfill to do that.

See [Official Document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html)